# How to create a custom attribute of option input and access it value in the component?

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have created a custom attribute for an option from a select input in order to access it value from component logic. I dont know how to do it but this approach his not working.

My template:

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="skillLevelsId">
     <option value="">-- Select a skill level --</option>
     <option *ngFor="let skillLevel of skillLevels" [value]="skillLevel" [chipValue]="chipValue">
       {{ skillLevel.skillLevel }}
     </option>
   </select>
```

I want to access from ts to the chipValue value from template:

```
Object.keys(this.filterMemberForm.controls).forEach((key) => {
      this.filterChips.push(this.filterMemberForm.controls[key].value);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you've defined correctly your reactive form and you have declared   `form: FormGroup` in your component, you can access any formControl value by:

```
this.form.get('formControlName')
```

In your case:

```
this.filterMemberForm.get('skillLevelsId')
```

Comment: but how I access to [chipValue] value??

Comment: do you mean that you want to add a new attribute chipValue ? please share the whole code, if it is that case, you can define a chipValue in skillLevel and access by skillLevel.chipValue without the custom input that you made @doubting

Comment: I want to access to chipvalue attribute from the component ts, not from the template. Something like this:    Object.keys(this.filterMemberForm.controls).forEach((key) => {
      this.filterChips.push(this.filterMemberForm.controls[key].chipValue);
    });